# xajax and codeigniter - blank page and xajax request URI error

Tags: codeigniter, xajax

I am unfortunately getting a blank page when trying to run a site locally. There are other people running it locally just fine, so I am wondering if it could be something to do with my LAMP environment.

When I attempt to load the site, it's nothing but a blank page. I've ran php index.php in console and the error I get is the following "xajax Error: xajax failed to automatically identify your Request URI.Please set the Request URI explicitly when you instantiate the xajax object.". I'm not quite sure how to handle this in CodeIgniter and or at all to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with LAMP configuration: check codeigniter folder permissions (add write permission to "logs" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I actually figured out what the problem was, it was like you said a problem with my LAMP configuration. Unfortunately XAMPP (which is what I am using and or was), the newest version uses PHP 5.3. Xajax doesn't support PHP 5.3 and this was causing the problems. After I went to an older version all was well!